# Many to many to many relationships with EF4 and Code First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I've got a problem I can't figure out how to express with CTP5 of Code First and EF4.

**EDIT: Added my old schema at the bottom that I'd like to replicate through CF**

Here's my specific scenario:

A Team is an abstract concept; it should exist with a specific set of players, in a specific division, in a specific season.

A concrete example of this in action from the NFL:

- 1996 (season) AFC Central (division) Houston Oilers (team)
- 1997 (season) AFC Central (division) Tennessee Oilers (team)
- 1999 (season) AFC Central (division) Tennessee Titans (team)
- 2002 (season) AFC South (division) Tennessee Titans (team)

These are all the same team. I want to be able to do the following:

```
// Titans team id = 17
var myTeam = myContext.Teams.Single(t => t.Id == 17)

// display players
foreach (var p in myTeam.Seasons[1999].Players)
{
    // Do something with the p here
}

// Display current division
Response.Write(myTeam.Seasons[2002].Division.Name);
```

I'm not sure of the specific query syntax within an ICollection member variable of myTeam.Seasons, but the concept should be the same none the less.

Can anyone shed some light on how you'd express this concept through CF in EF4 CF CTP5?
How would you express this through Code First?

Current SQL tables

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Season
(
    Id                INT IDENTITY(1,1)      NOT NULL,
    LeagueId          INT                    NOT NULL,
    [Name]            NVARCHAR(50)           NOT NULL,
    [Year]            CHAR(4)                NOT NULL,
    PrevSeasonId      INT            NULL

) ON [PRIMARY];

// Primary key
ALTER TABLE dbo.Season WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT PK_Season PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id) ON [PRIMARY];

CREATE TABLE dbo.Division
(
    Id       INT IDENTITY(1,1)      NOT NULL,
    DefaultName   NVARCHAR(50)           NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];

// Primary key
ALTER TABLE dbo.Division WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT PK_Division PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id) ON [PRIMARY];

// Key Relation Table
CREATE TABLE dbo.DivisionsInSeason
(
    DivisionId     INT                  NOT NULL,
    SeasonId       INT                  NOT NULL,
    DefaultName    NVARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL,
    Commissioner   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER     NOT NULL,
    ParentDivId    INT              NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];

// Primary Key
ALTER TABLE dbo.DivisionsInSeason WITH NOCHECK ADD  
    CONSTRAINT PK_DivisionsInSeason PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (DivisionId, SeasonId) ON [PRIMARY] ;

// Foreign Keys    
ALTER TABLE dbo.DivisionsInSeason WITH CHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT FK_DivisionsInSeason_Division FOREIGN KEY(DivisionId) REFERENCES dbo.Division(Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_DivisionsInSeason_Season FOREIGN KEY(SeasonId) REFERENCES dbo.Season(Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_DivisionsInSeason_User FOREIGN KEY(Commissioner) REFERENCES dbo.[User](Id);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Team
(
    Id       INT IDENTITY(1,1)      NOT NULL,
    DefaultName     NVARCHAR(50)           NOT NULL,
    DefShortName       NCHAR(3)            NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];

// Primary key
ALTER TABLE dbo.Team WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT PK_Team PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id) ON [PRIMARY] ;

// Key relationship table
CREATE TABLE dbo.TeamsInDivision
(
    TeamId         INT              NOT NULL,
    DivisionId     INT              NOT NULL,
    SeasonId       INT              NOT NULL,
    GeneralManager UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    Name           NVARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    ShortName      NCHAR(3)         NULL

) ON [PRIMARY];

// Check Constraints
ALTER TABLE dbo.TeamsInDivision ADD  
    CONSTRAINT PK_TeamsInDivision PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (TeamId, DivisionId, SeasonId) ON [PRIMARY];

// Foreign Keys    
ALTER TABLE dbo.TeamsInDivision WITH CHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT FK_TeamsInDivision_Team FOREIGN KEY(TeamId) REFERENCES dbo.Team(Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_TeamsInDivision_Division FOREIGN KEY(DivisionId) REFERENCES dbo.Division(Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_TeamsInDivision_Season FOREIGN KEY(SeasonId) REFERENCES dbo.Season(Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_TeamsInDivision_User FOREIGN KEY(GeneralManager) REFERENCES dbo.[User](Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be usefull

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2011/08/01/creating-a-many-to-many-mapping-using-code-first.aspx